# No puedo vincular el archivo JSON con Javascript y por ende no lo veo en HTML (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch

Estoy haciendo una web sobre busqueda de autos usados. Me falta crear un html con el login de usuarios y que esos usuarios puedan ingresar vehiculos al JSON para luego visualizarlos en el HTML. Pero esa todavia no es la cuestion.
Ahora el grave problema que tengo es que no puedo vincular el archivo autos.json al html como lo tenia anteriormente con el autos.js.
HTML

```
 <form id="formularioMarcas" class="caja">
        Selecciona:<br/>
        <select id="buscar">  
          <option value="default" onclick="traer()" selected>Selecciona una marca</option>
          <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
          <option value="BMW" >BMW</option>
          <option value="Chevrolet">Chevrolet</option>
          <option value="Dodge">Dodge</option>
          <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
          <option value="Mercedes Benz">Mercedes Benz</option>
          <option value="Renault">Renault</option>
          <option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
        </select><p/>
       <input type="submit" id="Reset" value="Reset" />
   </form>
   
   <div id="lista-autos" class="autos">
    <img src=" " id="imagen" class="main_img">
   </div>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
   <script src="autos.json"></script>
```

En esto agregue el *onclick=traer().*

ahora el app.js que mezcle todo. Lo que tenia y lo que deberia tener.
JS Lo que creo que deberia tener. Ya se que esta mal pero no se en que. Perdon no se si lo dije pero soy nuevo en el uso de Fetch.

```
/Recupera el elemento donde se mostrara la lista de autos
const lista_autos = document.getElementById('lista-autos')


fetch('autos.json')
.then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
})
.then(function(myJson) {
  var divAutos = document.getElementById('lista_autos');
  lista_autos = ""
  lista_autos += `<p><b>${myJson.marca}</b></p>`;
  lista_autos += `<p>To be or not to be? <b>${myJson.modelo}</b></p>`;
  lista_autos += `<p>There are <b>${myJson.year}</b></p>`;
  
  divAutos.innerHTML = lista_autos;
});
```

Este es con el que funcionaba...

```
//Funciona para renderizar la lista con la informacion de cada auto la cual puede recibir el parametro de "marca" que por defecto tiene el valor default
function renderListaAutos(marca = "default"){
   //Define un parametro para construir el html a insertar en el documento
   let html_lista_autos = ''
   
    //Recorre la lista de autos
   autos.forEach((auto) => {
     let html_info_auto = ''
        if(marca === "default"){
        html_info_auto = '<div>'+
          '<table>'+auto.modelo+' ' +auto.year+'</table>'+
        '</div>'
        }else{
        if(marca === auto.marca){
        html_info_auto = 
        `<div class="card-deck">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="${auto.img}" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"> ${auto.marca}</h5>
                <pre class="card-text"> &nbsp ${auto.modelo} , ${auto.year} \$${auto.precio} , ${auto.puertas} puertas , transmisión: ${auto.transmision}.</pre>
                
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>`
      }
     }
     
     html_lista_autos += html_info_auto
   })
   lista_autos.innerHTML = html_lista_autos  
}



function onChangeSelect(event){
renderListaAutos(event.target.value);
}

document.getElementById("buscar").addEventListener("change", onChangeSelect);
window.onload = () => {
 renderListaAutos()
}
```

Con el autos.app Este funcionaba perfecto.

Y del autos.json solo pongo esta pequeña lista. Tiene como 20 vehiculos pero bueno lo importante son las marca, modelo, año, precio, transmision.

```
[
    {
        "marca":"BMW",
        "modelo":"Serie 3",
        "year":2020,
        "precio":3000000,
        "puertas":4,
        "transmision":"Automática",
        "color":"Blanco"
        " img ": "https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_NQ_NP_655202-MLA49344293576_032022-O.webp"
     },
     {
        "marca":"Audi",
        "modelo":"A4",
        "year":2020,
        "precio":4000000,
        "puertas":4,
        "transmision":"Automática",
        "color": "Negro"
        "img": "https://imgcla.lavoz.com.ar/files/imagecache/ficha_aviso_628_418_sc/avisos/aviso_auto/aviso-auto--10768808.JPG"
     },
]
```

Si aunque sea, pudieran guiarme seria de muchisima ayuda!
Muchisimas gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leer el post.

Comment: autos.json es siempre la misma lista o es dinámico?? Con dinámico me refiero a que se va creando a partir de por ejemplo una base de datos. Por otro lado "fijo" sería que es un texto plano, donde para cambiarlo tu lo haces manual, cuál de las 2?

Comment: Si autos.json es un array de autos... Porque en el codigo accedes a myJson.marca? Deberias es acceder a cada uno de los elementos y sacar sus propiedades... Es decir myJson[0].marca, lo cual puede lograr con un ciclo cualquiera. Saludos.

Comment: Buenas muchachos. Si yussef es "fijo" lo cambiaría manual. O sea agregar autos.

Comment: Pipe porque la búsqueda es por marca en el html. Pero en el resultado tiene que aparecer todo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo.. ya lo resolvi. Dejo el codigo para quien lo necesite. Gracias a todos igualmente!

```
let autos= {};
async function cargarListaAutos(){
    autos = await fetch('./autos.json',  {headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json"
}})
.then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
})
.then(data => data);
}
```